# Remove Black dot from li and ul for all type

Tags: html, css

I have try to remove the black dot in list. Instead of that need to append `")"`

```css
li::before {
  content:")";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <h2>Ordered List without Dot</h2>

    <ol type="i">
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ol>
   
<ol type="a" >
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

The actual output is

```
 i) Coffee
ii) Tea
```

Answer (score 10):

try with `counter-reset`

```css
ol { 
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li { display: block; }
ol.alpha li:before {
  content: counter(item, lower-latin) " ) "; /*(a, b, c, ... z) */
  counter-increment: item ;
}
ol.roman li:before {
  content: counter(item, lower-roman) " ) "; /*(i, ii, iii, iv, v,)*/
  counter-increment: item ;
}

/* List type 
  decimal (1,2,3,4,)
  decimal-leading-zero(01,02,03,04 ...)
  lower-roman (i, ii, iii, iv, v, etc)
  upper-roman (I, II, III, IV, V, etc.)
  lower-latin or lower-alpha (a, b, c, ... z)
  upper-latin or upper-alpha  (A, B, C, ... Z)
  lower-greek (α, β, γ, ...)
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <h2>Ordered List without Dot</h2>

    <ol class="alpha" >
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ol>
   
<ol class="roman">
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I need the output as i)Coffee and a)Coffee

Comment: Thank you. Can u suggest me,how can i get this for all list type?

Answer (score 0):

Use in this way :

```
 ul.a {list-style-type: none;}


<ul class="a">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks ,but i need to remove the black dot not the list style.

Comment: but that's exactly how you can do that...?

Answer (score 0):

Add this style (or any other selector that would target lists where you need to remove the default styling)

```
  ul, ol {
   list-style-type: none;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This keeps them right-aligned. Add a width to the ::before rules to make them left-aligned.

```css
ol.i, ol.a {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-reset: item;
}
ol.i > li, ol.a > li {
    position: relative;
}
ol.i > li::before,
ol.a > li::before {
    counter-increment: item;
    position: absolute;
    right: 100%;
    padding-right: 0.5em;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
ol.i > li::before {
    content: counter(item, lower-roman) ")";
}
ol.a > li::before {
    content: counter(item, lower-latin) ")";
}
```

```html
<html><body>

    <h2>Custom list counter</h2>

    <ol class="i">
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ol>
   
    <ol class="a" >
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
    </ol>
    
</body></html>
```